# Precisely what do 净入学率 (~"net enrollment rate") and 毛入学率 (~"gross enrollment rate") mean?

Tags: meaning, difference

I'm reading about literacy in China, and encounter the terms 净入学率 and 毛入学率, but I'm unclear on their precise meaning:

> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%87%80): 净 (jìng​) ... / net (income, exports etc) / ...
> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%AF%9B): 毛 (máo) ... / raw / ...
> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%85%A5%E5%AD%A6%E7%8E%87): 入学率 (rù​xué​lǜ​) percentage of children who enter school

The above seem to be the closest relevant definition.  Putting the terms into Youdao gives ["net enrollment rate"](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%87%80%E5%85%A5%E5%AD%A6%E7%8E%87) and ["gross enrollment rate"](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%AF%9B%E5%85%A5%E5%AD%A6%E7%8E%87).  I have no idea what the difference here is.

Moreover [this news article](https://finance.sina.com.cn/china/gncj/2021-06-21/doc-ikqcfnca2207433.shtml) lists a 毛入学率 of 102.5%, which sounds mathematically impossible.

> [image: Screenshot of a news article showing a 毛入学率 of 102.5%]
> <sub>[从“文盲大国”到教育大国 新中国最大程度实现了教育公平](https://finance.sina.com.cn/china/gncj/2021-06-21/doc-ikqcfnca2207433.shtml)，中国青年报，2021年06月21日</sub>

**Question**: Precisely what do 净入学率 (~"net enrollment rate") and 毛入学率 (~"gross enrollment rate") mean?

Comment: Gross - 总量, 总额 (n); 总的 (adj). 毛 - hair, fur, mane. The gross enrollment rate should be 总入学率, I've never heard of 毛入学率, but it might be defined in China with special meaning so that the gross rate can be  > 100%.

Comment: This article can help. https://rich01.com/1-profit-margin/

Comment: From the article cited above, 毛利率 ＝（營業收入－營業成本）／營業收入 x 100%, we can rewrite as 毛入学率 = (現下入学人數 -  過去入学人數)/現下入学人數 x 100%, since typically the result in ( ) will be less than the denominator unless the past number of enrolled student is negative, the listed rate does not make sense.

Comment: Okay, it can make sense if 毛入学率 is defined as the "net growth rate" of student enrollment, 毛入学率 = (現下入学人數 - **過去入学人數**)/**過去入学人數** x 100%, so the result can be greater than 100%.

Comment: Wouldn't a Baidu search answer the question? It's just a way that Government measures the enrollment rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

初中阶段净入学率 = [image]  × 100%

初中阶段毛入学率 =
[image]  × 100%